# Displaying the Years and Months from current date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date column in my table with the format '01-JAN-99'. I need to display the difference between the current date, using sysdate, and the dates in my table. But I have to display it by Years and Months. So if the date is 148 months ago, then it would display 12 Years and 4 Months.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the column is actually a `DATE` (which does not have a format) rather than a `VARCHAR2` that represents a date (which would have a format), you would want something like

```
TRUNC( months_between( sysdate, date_column )/ 12 ) || ' Years and ' ||
TRUNC( MOD( months_between( sysdate, date_column ), 12 ) || ' Months.'
```

This assumes that if the difference is a fractional number of months that you want to ignore the fractional amount.  If you want to round to the nearest month, replace the `TRUNC` with a `ROUND` in the calculation of the number of months.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just another quick question, does it really matter if I use the same table alias twice? For example, I have something like SELECT e.column, i.column FROM table1 e, table2 i; and later I have CREATE VIEW view AS SELECT e.column, i.column FROM table1 e, table2 i; and it gives me a "name is already used by an existing object" error but the view seems to have been created with no problems.

Comment: @user2616744 - That should be a separate question but, yes, it does matter.  You can't have two columns in a view named the same thing just like you can't have two columns in a table with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Script:

```
SELECT TRUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (sysdate, date_col) / 12) || ' YEARS '
       || MOD (TRUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (sysdate, date_col)), 12) || ' MONTHS '
       || (TO_DATE (sysdate) – ADD_MONTHS (date_col,TRUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (sysdate, date_col)))) || ' DAYS'
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(yy, '04/01/1999 00:00:00', GETDATE()) AS Years, DATEDIFF(m, '04/01/1999 00:00:00', GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(yy, '04/01/1999 00:00:00', GETDATE()) * 12) AS Months
```

Ideally the date ('04/01/1999') would be a column or a parameter to avoid repeating.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` is a SQL Server function.  It's not something that is available in Oracle

Comment: Then do not tag it as SQL - my mistake though I did not see the oracle tag.

Comment: The `SQL` tag is for questions that involve the Structured Query Language.  This is very much a SQL question.  It happens to be about the Oracle database's implementation of SQL.  If you want to look for questions about SQL Server, you'd need to look for tags like `sql-server`.